# Get the indexPath of the relevant element in a loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, indexpath

I'm working in a project in Swift 3.0 and I have a loop that would give me the state of an object (gives a boolean value in a an array sequence). My requirement is if the element state is "true" I wants to get the relevant index path of that, so using that `indexPath` I can get the whole object from my original array. So inside a loop how can i get that as well? My partially done code is below. In a comment I have stated where I wants to pass this `indexPath`.

```
func tapFunction(sender: UIButton) {

        // This gives me the selected indexPath
        print("ID :",sender.accessibilityIdentifier!)


        if let rowIndexString =  sender.accessibilityIdentifier, let rowIndex = Int(rowIndexString) {
        self.sateOfNewSongArray[rowIndex] = !self.sateOfNewSongArray[rowIndex]
        }
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected


        for (element) in self.sateOfNewSongArray {

         //This is where I wants to pass the rowIndex that became true
            if element == true {
              selectedSongList.addingObjects(from: [songList[rowIndex]])

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try with an updated answer and let me know, if you have any confusion.

Comment: the type of my arrays are NSArray. So this wont work

Comment: don't use NSArray in Swift, Declare your array as I've shown in last sample block. Sample string array: let selectedSongList = [String]()   Share your array declaration here, I'll help you to convert your arrays into Swift arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note**: Make sure your array 'sateOfNewSongArray' has **boolean** types
>   of elements

Try following solutions:

**Sample Code 1:** According to your current code in your question.

```
func tapFunction(sender: UIButton) {

    // This gives me the selected indexPath
    print("ID :",sender.accessibilityIdentifier!)


    if let rowIndexString =  sender.accessibilityIdentifier, let rowIndex = Int(rowIndexString) {
        self.sateOfNewSongArray[rowIndex] = !self.sateOfNewSongArray[rowIndex]
    }
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected


  for (index, element) in self.sateOfNewSongArray.enumerated() {

    if element {
       if let songName:String = songList[index] {
          selectedSongList.append(songName)
       }
    }
  }

}
```

**Sample Code 2:** More easier and concise.

```
func tapFunction(sender: UIButton) {

    // This gives me the selected indexPath
    print("ID :",sender.accessibilityIdentifier!)

    if let rowIndexString =  sender.accessibilityIdentifier, let rowIndex = Int(rowIndexString) {
       if let songName:String = songList[rowIndex] {
          selectedSongList.append(songName)
       }

   }

}
```

`enumerated()` is a function, returns sequence of pairs enumerating with index and element of array (by iterating elements of array)

Here is basic sample code, for your understanding. Copy and execute this code:

```
let songList =  [“cat”, “dog”, “elephant”]
let sateOfNewSongArray = [false, true, false]
let selectedSongList = [String]()

for (index, element) in self.sateOfNewSongArray.enumerated() {

      if element {
         if let animalName:String = songList[index] {
              selectedSongList.append(animalName)
         }
      }
}

print(“selectedSongList - \(selectedSongList)”)
```

Comment: imagine in my "songList" array I have [cat,dog,elephant] and in my sateOfNewSongArray give me [fales,true,fales], Therefore since the second element gives me "true" my requirement is to get "dog" from "songList" array. You get what Im saying ?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to swift can you please do it respect to my code above. My requirement is to pass the index to the songList and get the relevant item.